# How to pass arguments to modal window from within data table in Prime Faces 6.2?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I need to have a link showing a modal window when pushed near a row value in a data table as shown down here but apparently my way to pass a value right from the data table via request parameters to the modal window is wrong. So I receive blank area inside window. Here the picture of how it looks and a code sample (yellow triangle is a link):
[image]

```
<p:dataTable id="ticketList" value="#{tickets}" var="ticket">

        <p:column headerText="Статус экспорта">
            <h:outputText value="#{ticket.exportStatus.caption}"/>
            <p:commandLink id="ticketErrorShowlink"
                           action="ticketError"
                           oncomplete="PF('exportError').show();">
                <h:graphicImage url="/images/shim.gif" style="border:0; vertical-align:center" width="5"/>
                <h:graphicImage id="headImageHelp" url="/images/mess_warning.gif" title="Ошибки экспорта"
                                style="border:0; vertical-align:bottom"/>
                <f:param name="errorText" value="#{ticket.errors}"/>
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<p:dialog id="ticketErrorModalPanel" header="Ошибки экспорта" widgetVar="exportError">
        <f:facet name="controls">
            <h:outputLink id="phidelink" value="#hide" onclick="PF('exportError').hide();">
                <h:graphicImage value="/images/close.png" style="border:0; cursor:pointer;"/>
            </h:outputLink>
        </f:facet>

        <p:panelGrid columns="1" columnsWidth="540px">
            <h:outputText value="#{requestParameters.errorText}" escape="false" />
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:commandLink id="closeLink" oncomplete="PF('exportError').hide();" value="Закрыть" />
</p:dialog>
```

So, is there any rules to follow either passing parameters from data table or when receiving them in a  tag to resolve such problem? Thanks for your answers in advance. Any additional info will be added if there's a need.

Comment: Maybe you can do `<h:outputText value="#{ticket.errors}"/>` in the dialog and update="ticketErrorModalPanel" in the `<commandLink`

Comment: I've tried to but unfortunately it gives the same result

Comment: You can use `f:setPropertyActionListener` inside `p:commandLink` for setting parameter, which will be displayed in `p:dialog`

Comment: Could you clarify how it should work given that there're more than one row in a table with links to modal window? I can create a list of all error texts in a backing bean, for instanse. But how I will identify which list item should be attached to?

Comment: So you did get it to work in PrimeFaces 6.1? And check the PrimeFaces showcase. Example in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: added `<p:ajax>` that sets value from the data table to a backing bean.

```
<h:form id="protocolForm">
  <p:dataTable id="ticketList" value="#{tickets}" var="ticket">
    <p:column headerText="Статус экспорта">
      <h:outputText value="#{ticket.exportStatus.caption}"/>
      <p:commandLink id="ticketErrorShowlink"
                     oncomplete="PF('exportError').show()">

         <h:graphicImage url="/images/shim.gif" style="border:0; vertical-align:center" width="5"/>
         <h:graphicImage id="headImageHelp" url="/images/mess_warning.gif" title="Ошибки экспорта"
                         style="border:0; vertical-align:bottom"/>
         <p:ajax listener="#{protocolForm.setErrors(ticket.errors)}" update=":protocolForm:ticketErrorPanelGroup"/>
      </p:commandLink>
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

// dialog down there
```

Put a modal window to the `<h:panelGroup>`:

```
// data table
  <h:panelGroup id="ticketErrorPanelGroup">
    <p:dialog id="ticketErrorModalPanel" header="Ошибки экспорта" widgetVar="exportError">
        <f:facet name="controls">
            <h:outputLink id="phidelink" value="#hide" onclick="PF('exportError').hide();">
                <h:graphicImage value="/images/close.png" style="border:0; cursor:pointer;"/>
            </h:outputLink>
        </f:facet>

        <p:panelGrid columns="1" columnsWidth="540px">
            <h:outputText value="#{protocolForm.getErrors()}" escape="false" />
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:commandLink id="closeLink" oncomplete="PF('exportError').hide()" value="Закрыть" />
    </p:dialog>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Also, there's a backing bean - ProtocolForm to get/set values (it's created by Spring Web Flow so there isn't the @MenagedBean annotation).

```
public class ProtocolForm { 
   private String errors;

   // getter/setter
}
```

After setting query complete the window opens getting the value.

Answer (score 0):

you can put an id to the outputtext in the dialog.

```
  <p:panelGrid columns="1" columnsWidth="540px">
        <h:outputText id="exportErrorText" value=" " escape="false" />
    </p:panelGrid>
```

then do something like this in your button

```
<p:commandLink id="ticketErrorShowlink"
                               action="ticketError"
                               oncomplete="document.getElementById('exportErrorText').innerHTML = '#{ticket.errors}'; PF('exportError').show();">
```

Comment: and then maybe you don't need a commandlink, just put onclick="...." on the images, with the same content of the oncomplete